# Non-generic subclass of generic interface

Tags: java, generics

I have some generic interface

```
interface Animal<T> {}
```

And I have a subclass that I only want to extend `Animal<Object>`. So I did

```
class Pet implements Animal<Object>
```

I have some method that should only compile if both parameters have matching type:

```
<T> T apply(T source, Animal<T> target)
```

I was wondering, why does this compile

```
String source = "test";
Pet pet = new Pet();
apply(source, pet);
```

It seems that since the type of source is `String`, and the type of pet is `Pet` which implements `Animal<Object>`, there should be a type mismatch here and cause a compiler error, but I found that this compiles and was wondering if someone could explain why.

Comment: Because a `String` is an `Object`!?

Comment: source param is only T and not Animal<T>. Nothing says source and target must be the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are calling method `apply` without explicitly specifying a type between angle brackets, you are relying on the compiler to *infer* one for you. If you try assigning the result to a variable of some type, say `String`, the compiler will tell you which type it has inferred for example:

```
String r = Animal.apply(source, pet);
```

> Type mismatch: Cannot convert from Object to String

In which case you know that `T` was inferred as `Object`. If you pass two `String` instances, `T` will be inferred as `String`:

```
String r = Animal.apply("A", "B");
```

Note that Java allows you to explicitly specify the type argument for a generic method (called *type witness*). This is useful to check assumptions you might have about how the type parameter will be bound:

```
Animal.<Object>apply(source, pet);
```

More information: [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)

Answer (score 0):

String is also an Object (all non-primitives are also Objects). so, the apply method here works fine, and binds T to object, at which point everything lines up. It's like having a method: `foo(Object x)`, and calling it as `foo("")` which is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

You are <strike>casting</strike> binding the generic in

```
class Pet implements Animal<Object>
```

to the object class. Everything in java is a descendant of the object class so the compiler will have no issue here. When you declare that your class implements Animal you need to bind it to a specific type to restrict what it will accept for parameters.

Comment: Just for reference, this is called 'binding', not 'casting', at least, if we follow the parlance used in the Java Language Specification. Just nitpicking  :)

Comment: You're right. I got it later on in the post but missed it at the beginning.